# error 500 on IIS FastCGI but no clue despite multiple error loggings activated

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, fastcgi

I host two WordPress sites on a Windows 2019 Server, IIS 10, PHP 8.2 with FastCGI.

The two sites use exactly the same themes and plugins, in same versions.

One site works fine and the other generates 500 error on FastCGI with PHP 8.2, even when I deactivate all themes and plugins and use the default WordPress 2024 theme.

But it works fine if I swicth the FastCGI to use PHP 7.4.

When set with PHP 8.2:

I have enabled PHP error log: only deprecation level errors, and on both sites.

I have enabled WordPress debug log: only deprecation level errors, and on both sites.

I have enables Failed Trace Request log on IIS, I get this but I can't find any valuable information inside.

[error log file](https://demo.knowledgeplaces.com/error500/fr000271.xml)

You may need to view this error log file with Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer compatibility mode.

If someone can give me a clue, or tell me which additionnal error logging feature I can use, it would be very helpful, as I am completely stucked here.

Comment: `only deprecation level errors`...why? This could miss a lot of things. Try turning on _all_ errors in PHP

Comment: There are years of breaking changes you need to adapt to on PHP side (which is the common cause of FastCGI process crash in the log), and also deprecation of PHP on IIS support from Microsoft. So, you are on a tough job.

Comment: @ADyson I have already enabled all errors and  I get only depreciation errors. And I get exactly the same errors on the site which runs fine.

Comment: @Lex as I mentioned, I have a site exactly the same, with same depreciation errors, and it runs fine, no 500 errors.

Comment: Logging can only take you this far. The next is to debug the site (pho-cgi.exe) to reveal more details.